# How can I use Search with an API endpoint as my source? Is this possible with semantic-ui-react?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I would like to use an API endpoint to pull search results in react-semantic-ui. So far the examples given work with local source. The one that seems to implement an API is via **Semantic-UI** using jquery. **Semantic-UI-React** does not seem to have examples where results can come from an API.

so far, I have my handleSearchChange fetching data from the API into state. I then pass the response data to my results:

```
handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {
const { fetchAPIData, response } = this.props;
fetchAPIData(value);
this.setState({ isLoading: true, value, results: response });

setTimeout(
  () =>
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false
    }),
  300
);
```

};

I then call resultRenderer passing my source which is rendering the results via a Grid and/or even a List.

```
return (
  <Search
    fluid
    placeholder="Search"
    style={searchWidth}
    loading={isLoading}
    minCharacters={2}
    showNoResults={false}
    selectFirstResult={false}
    resultRenderer={source}
    onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
    onSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}
    results={results}
    value={value}
  />
);
```

This seems to work and load results when a search occurs. However, I reckon since this is merely a hack, I am getting this console error:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `title` is marked as
required in `SearchResult`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

I understand the error well, but I do not want to use my source with title, description, price etc since my result is coming from an API.

Another error is:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" 
prop.
```

I have tried adding the key as:

```
const source = ({ id, username }) => (
  <Grid key={id} content={username}
......
......
......
);
```

and or:

```
const source = ({ id, username }) => (
  <List key={id} content={username} />
);
```

But this does not solve it.

My question thus is, is it possible to use an API with the Search in Semantic-UI-React and if so, how can it efficiently be implemented?

Thanks